# Matlab pixel and histogram distance

Tags: matlab

are there any matlab functions that perform the following :
[image]

NxM are the dimensions of the image. I,j are the pixel value(Red for chanel 1, Green for chanel 2, Blue for chanel 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the first distance by

```
d1 = sqrt(sum((A(:)-B(:)).^2));
```

and the second by

```
% Create histograms
hA = hist(A(:),255);
hB = hist(B(:),255);

% Calculate distance
d2 = sqrt(sum((hA-hB).^2));
```

Comment: so you just do the maths ? Thanks a lot, i didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Since there wasn't a build in function that will do.